# Javascript convert [url=] to html link

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm currently trying to convert this:

`[url=http://example.com] this is a link [/url]`

to a standard html link:

```
<a href=http://example.com>this is a link</a>
```

So far, I can convert the url string to a link, however the `[url=] [/url]` still remains and I'm not sure how to filter it out.

```
message.replace(/(\b(https?):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>")
```

How can I filter out the `[url=] [/url]` in the regex and also ensure `this is a link` (text defined by the user) also remains?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to add it to your replace regex:

```
message.replace(/\[url=(\b(https?):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])\]/ig, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>")
                 ^^^^^^
```

Though you still have the last url tag and you can make things easier with negated classes:

```
message.replace(/\[url=([^\]]+)\]\s*(.*?)\s*\[\/url\]/ig, "<a href='$1'>$2</a>")
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/uF9rM1)

EDIT: Made the closing tag a literal because of potential other tags

Answer (score 0):

I would do that in 3 steps:

- Replace `[url=` with `<a href="`
- Replace `[/url]` with `</a>`
- Replace `]` with `">`

But that's just an opinion. I usually like to keep it simple, and move on to the next problem.